# Implementing Incremental Authorization in passport.js with the Google API OAuth 2.0

Tags: google-api, gmail, passport.js, google-oauth

I'm currently using passport.js with the strategy from passport-google-oauth20 and I want to implement incremental authorization. I'm using yarn as my package manager and my server also uses the Nodejs and Express packages.

When a user first logs in, all I need is their basic gmail information like their email address, so I specify the "email" scope:

```
router.get('/', 
    passport.authenticate('google', {
    hd: '(my domain)',
    scope: ['email'],
    accessType: 'offline',
    prompt: 'consent'
}));
```

When they are on a different page, they can request that the site send an email from their account so I now need to add the "https://www.mail.google.com" scope to the session. I couldn't find any documentation for it on the [passport.js website](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/) and google has a [page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#incrementalAuth) on it, but I don't think that's setup since I'm using passport.js. I've tried using

```
router.post('/sendEmail',
passport.authenticate('google', {
    hd: '(my domain)',
    scope: ['https://www.mail.google.com'],
    accessType: 'offline',
    include_granted_scopes: true,
    prompt: 'consent',
    failerRedirect: '/auth',
    successRedirect: '/google/authorizedSendEmail'
}));
```

but I get the error

> Failed to load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&prompt=consent&hd=(myDomain)&response_type=code&redirect_uri=(myCallbackURL)&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mail.google.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&client_id=(usersID).apps.googleusercontent.com:
>
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '(my domain)' is therefore not allowed access.

when requesting it.

If I include "https://www.mail.google.com" in the initial scope and don't have the second authentication call, then it does work; an email is sent from the user's account. But, of course that isn't incremental authorization.

Also, I think incremental authorization should have its own tag, but I don't have the rep to do so, could someone add it please?

Comment: Small correction to the question: the scope I actually used to successfully  send an email was https://www.mail.google.com, not https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

Comment: passport is an authentication library. It's not reasonable to expect it to do authorization, especially incremental authorization. I suggest that for the Inc auth you should simply forget about any library and send the appropriate http redirect yourself.